# Why am I getting a memory exception on deleting a char*

Tags: c++, string, algorithm, memory, memory-management

I am attempting to write my own string class (so I can learn more) and while doing so I noticed I ran into an issue with how the char data is being deleted, when the program closes the destructor of string will be called and there will be a heap error on deleting the data

```
#include <string.h>

template<typename T>
class String
{
protected:
    T* mData;

public:
    String(const T* data);
    ~String();
};

template<typename T>
String<T>::String(const T* data)
{
    if(data != NULL)
    {
        mData = new T[strlen(data)];
        strcpy(mData, data);
    }
}

template<typename T>
String<T>::~String()
{
    if(mData != NULL)
    {
        delete [] mData;
        mData = 0;
    }
}

int main(void)
{
    String<char> Test("Test");

    return(0);
}
```

Comment: No need to test for NULL before deleting (or set the value to 0 afterwords).

Comment: You need to obey the rule of three. Otherwise you will crash after the first copy.

Comment: You are correct, I was violating the rule of three (I wanted to have a simple test case)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
 mData = new T[strlen(data)];
        strcpy(mData, data);
```

You are allocating one item too few, strcpy copies the nul terminating byte as well as the string

Comment: That was it exactly, I completely forgot about that. Thank you for the help.

Answer (score 0):

You should use "memcpy" and "memset" functions instead of that like strcpy:

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstring/memcpy/

Comment: By using 'memcpy' functions you're working with memory-blocks which is fast. Also the 'strcpy' is insecure because it can results in overflow as in your case, there is the 'strlcpy' function wich is secure. When you use memory-block functions you have full memory control. Personally I would prefer two string clasess one for the char type and other for wchar_t type both inheriting from the same generic abstract class (interface) rather than using a template (generic).

Answer (score 0):

You must be careful about operator new throwing an exception in your constructor. If that happens, you must make sure you have initialized your data pointer to nullptr, otherwize, the destructor will be called and try to delete some random address.

```
#include <cstring>

template<typename T>
class string {
    protected:
        T * data_;
    public:
        string(T const * data);
        ~string();
};

template<typename T>
string<T>::string(T const * data)
try {
    if(!data) data_ = 0;
    else {
        data_ = new T[std::strlen(data) + 1];
        std::strcpy(data_, data);
    }
} catch(...) {
    data_ = 0;
}

template<typename T>
string<T>::~string() {
    delete[] data_;
}

int main() {
    string<char> test("test");
    return 0;
}
```